# Skype chat bot framework - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I'm new to the bot framework and working on the skype chat bot by using node SDK.

I have JSON tree array which provide me the id and names for tree data.

```
treeName = tree.parse({
    "id": 1,
    "title": "menu",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "company _ data",
            "children": [{"id": 111}]
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "title": "adhoc data test ",
            "children": [{"id": 121}, {"id": 122}]
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "title": "quit",
            "children": [{"id": 131}, {"id": 132}]
        }
    ]
});
```

Code for get the title from tree.

```
var node1 = treeName.first(function (node) {
    return node.model.id === 1;
});
```

Array

```
var firstChild = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < node1.model.children.length; i++) {
            firstChild.push(node1.model.children[i].title);
        }
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "What scenario would you like to run? ",firstChild );
```

When I'm trying to get the id it will work well but if I want to get title in one array then I get this error:

```
/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: choice.trim is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have defined the variable 'choice' anywhere.

```
treeName.title
```

or

```
treename.children[X].title
```

The first one would, in this case, return 'menu', whereas the second one returns "company_data", or "adhoc data test", etc.

You cannot use .trim() on arrays or objects.